# Need to clear client side validation of EnumDropDownListFor when user chooses valid option

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, razor, enumdropdownlistfor

It validates with error if user clicks Submit button on page without selecting a valid value in ddl; however, when user does then go ahead and select a value, the error does not clear as it does for a textbox. I've got:

```
    public enum PoolDeckMaterialsEnum
    {
        Pavers,
        Concrete,
        [Display(Name = "N/A")]
        NotApplicable
    }
```

and

```
    [EnumDataType(typeof(PoolDeckMaterialsEnum))]
    [Required]
    public PoolDeckMaterialsEnum? PoolDeckMaterials { get; set; }
```

and

```
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PoolDeckMaterials, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.PoolDeckMaterials, "--- Select ---", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PoolDeckMaterials, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Unobtrusive jquery-validation?

Comment: @section Scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

Comment: bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js",
      "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                        "~/Scripts/expressive.annotations.validate.js"));

Comment: Not sure what else to do! I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following to immediately clear the validation error on selection:

```
//04/10/20 kk Had to do the below to clear the val immediately on selection
$("#PoolDeckMaterials").change(function () {
    $("#PoolDeckMaterials").blur(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Repro Steps:

1. Open page

   - change enum value
   - error message disapear forever
2. Open page

   - Click submit
   - change enum
   - validation message is working

Edit:
there should be some bugs by default. Regarding to validation registration.

Comment: Not quite sure I get what you're suggesting. First of all, the validation needs to occur without hitting the submit button. Secondly, when I choose a valid enum, the error message does not disappear as it should.